# MySQL - COUNT and MAX in same query. MAX ignoring WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I am executing the following script:

```
SELECT  a.*,
    gg.image as 'recent_image_file' 
FROM 

(   SELECT  c.cid, 
            c.category_name AS 'cat_name',
            COUNT(g.id) AS image_count,
            c.category_image AS 'images',
            c.estgendpref,
            MAX(n.id) as 'recent_image'
    FROM tbl_category c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_gallery_category g 
        ON c.cid=g.cat_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_gallery n 
        ON n.id=g.image_id

    WHERE n.date_active < NOW()
    GROUP BY c.cid
    ORDER BY c.category_name ASC
) a

INNER JOIN tbl_gallery gg
    ON a.recent_image = gg.id;
```

Everything is returning fine except the MAX(n.id) ignores the WHERE clause and returns the top id for the category. How do I get the MAX(n.id) to return the max for the resultset including the WHERE clause? Thanks.

Comment: Note that `WHERE n.date_active < NOW()` will convert the LEFT JOINs to INNER JOINs. Are you sure the condition is correct?

Comment: Include `MAX(n.date_active) as max_date` to the subquery SELECT clause. Does it return something greater than `NOW()`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - Thanks. I did so and no it doesnt. It looks like the query is performing as expected. My bad. Using MAX(id) was never ideal. I need the query to return the most recent id based on the date_active. This is not necessarily the MAX(id) however but couldnt think of any way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: "Using MAX(id) was never ideal" - There is nothing really wrong with your query. This is a good solution (IMHO). You can however use INNER JOIN.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel MAX(id) isnt ideal because there could be another lower ID but with a more recent date. This is actually causing the problem right now. I need the recent_image to be the most recent_image (based on date_active) Could you give a little more detail on how I could use an INNER JOIN to achieve this. Im sure it is simple, but I have been banging my head against a wall for 2 days now. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I was just about to edit my question and it came to me. MAX isnt what I am after, I am looking for something along the lines of TOP or FIRST from the ordered resultset.

Comment: INNER JOIN won't change anything because you are already using it (you just don't know that (-; ). You could use `MAX(n.date_active)` instead of `MAX(n.id)`. But if `n.date_active` is not unique, you will need another solution (e.g. correlated subquery).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the where condition  in on clause  adding a proper AND  .. otherwise the where work as inner join condition

```
SELECT  a.*,
    gg.image as 'recent_image_file' 
FROM 

(   SELECT  c.cid, 
            c.category_name AS 'cat_name',
            COUNT(g.id) AS image_count,
            c.category_image AS 'images',
            c.estgendpref,
            MAX(n.id) as 'recent_image'
    FROM tbl_category c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_gallery_category g  ON c.cid=g.cat_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_gallery n ON n.id=g.image_id and n.date_active < NOW()
    GROUP BY c.cid
    ORDER BY c.category_name ASC
) a

INNER JOIN tbl_gallery gg
    ON a.recent_image = gg.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

So with thanks to those who advised, I found the WHERE clause was being used. However, MAX(id) was not what was really wanted as a lower id could have a larger date. The following works a charm.

```
SELECT  c.cid, 
            c.category_name AS 'cat_name',
            COUNT(g.id) AS image_count,
            c.category_image AS 'images',
            c.estgendpref,
            recent.id  as 'recent_image',
            recent.date_active,
            recent.image as 'recent_image_file' 
    FROM tbl_category c
    INNER JOIN tbl_gallery_category g 
        ON c.cid=g.cat_id
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_gallery WHERE date_active <= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_active DESC, id DESC ) recent
        ON recent.id = g.image_id

    GROUP BY c.cid
    ORDER BY c.category_name ASC
```